# Django custom form not rendering

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-models

Total newbie here. I am creating a custom registration form for my homepage. I did following:

1. Create formreg.py

> ```
> class RegForm(forms.Form):
>     email = forms.EmailField()
>     password=forms.PasswordInput()
>     password2=forms.PasswordInput()
>     phone= forms.CharField(max_length=10)
> ```

2. In Index.html(where the form is), I wrote following inside form tag:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  {{ form.email.errors }}
  <label for="{{form.email.id_for_label}}">
    <b>Email</b>
  </label>
  {{ form.email }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}">
    <b>Password</b>
  </label>
  {{ form.password }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  <label for="register_password2">
    <b>Re-enter Password</b>
  </label>
  {{ form.password2 }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  <label for="phone">
    <b>Phone Number</b>
  </label>
  {{ form.phone }}
</div>
```

3. In views.py I added following:

> ```
> def register(request):
>     registered = False
>     if request.method == 'POST':
>         form = RegForm(request.POST)
>         if form.is_valid():
>              return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
>     else:
>         form=RegForm()
>     return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})
> ```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot understand. Please help.

Comment: assuming that ` it's not a typo, i ask, can RegForm be executed without parameters?

Comment: I may be wrong but you haven't got a submit button in that template ...

Comment: @jvc26 I haven't showed that part. This is inside a form tag and with Submit button.

Comment: @JoãoVilaça Sorry, did not get you.

Comment: You have that register method between ``, is that a typo or..? And i asked if on the "else" statement, the RegForm method can be called without params

Comment: @JoãoVilaça Yeah that was a typo. About else statement, I am trying to follow this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: I've done a lot of stuff on django before, and a major bummer were the includes. Are you including everything? do you get any error at all on the console?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm and no, I don't see any error :( Unless I am using wrong reference somewhere, I don't see any error.

Comment: Can you clarify more about what is not working? What do you get when you load the form? When you submit the form?

Comment: I do not see the form elements rendered. I see only labels and the form fields are not rendered at all. @OrenD

Comment: That's because the method is executing the else statement everytime, so 'form' is always empty.

Comment: @JoãoVilaça Okay, shouldn't the register be called when I click submit? What should I change to render form correctly? I will handle data entered later. First I want to test if form is rendered correctly.

Comment: Can you add the urls.py definition for this page?

Comment: @JoãoVilaça How do I do that? If that's required to just render the form for now.

Comment: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html , and go down to 'Making a contact form' , you did everything right, but the problem lies on the absence of some link, i mean, passing the data through the files. Try this link, if you still can't do it just comment here and we'll go to a titanpad to see all the code together.

Comment: @JoãoVilaça Still cannot solve the problem. You're right, there's a link missing and do not know which one.

Comment: chill, we'll find it, join me @ https://titanpad.com/jnZ9p1pJwm

Comment: @JoãoVilaça On debugging, it now enters index function in views! But it is not returning form. I'm on titanpad 2 more mins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has to do with the src root on pycharm and the lack of import in the file views.py and urls.py.

Comment: Kudos to your patience. :) Thanks for spending more than 45 mins and helping me in fixing it.